# jQuery and google.load conflict

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to add elastislide but due to some reason elastislide() not working.Any solution?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict()</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.vikal.com.au/css/front-end/test/jquerypp.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.vikal.com.au/css/front-end/test/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( '#carousel' ).elastislide();
alert('helo');
```

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: A fiddle may help debug your problem.

Comment: Any reason you need to use jquery 1.3.2?

Comment: After google.load , $( '#carousel' ).elastislide();  is not working but when i remove google.load ,its working properly .

Comment: And the error is "this.$items.detach is not a function in jquery.elastislide.js",when i use google.load.